# How to compile a C# program that doesn't show "Unknown Publisher" when executed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2013

I work for a school district and am doing some light programming, making technician tools etc.  I don't have (and the school won't front for) a code signing certificate.  What can I do/implement on my domain so that the programs I write don't come up as "Unknown Publisher".  I am presently developing on Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.  My programs required Administrator access and using ClickOnce seems to clash with the settings.  Please be gentle as this is my first post on SO.

EDIT:  The school system won't buy me a Verisign/Comodo code signing certificate due to my limited usage and the fact that my programs won't be deployed beyond the confines of our Domain.  I did have the admin of the CA server on our domain issue me a certificate; however, the program still says that the program is from an Unknown Publisher.  Does it not verify against the domain CA server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685576/why-does-my-signed-click-once-application-say-it-has-an-unknown-publisher see the first answer. You must buy certificate to sign your application. You may want to publish your program through the school site which will make your program more trustable by users , but you can't change unknown publisher

Comment: I think each developer have a unique "Key". When they are complied , that "key" would be able to read by microsoft verifier. If the key matches thier database. They display the developer name. Sorry If I'm wrong, If anybody have better explaination please explain it to OP.

Answer (score 2):

When I properly configure my domain's CA certificate server, I can have it issue code signing certificates that will be recognized and supported by the local domain's workstations.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875810.aspx

Thank you @Poormrockthe3years for pointing me in the right direction to find the correct terminology to search by.